# Normalize a Windows path or URI using RegEx in .NET

Tags: .net, regex, windows, path, normalization

I'm trying to build a regular expression that I can use to **match all duplicate slashes** in a local Windows path or URI and then replacing them by a single slash, **while leaving the URI scheme or local drive parts unaltered**.

This are the examples I'm testing against:

```
http://www.tempuri.org//path//////to/file.ext
c:/path-to/file.ext
c://path-to/file.ext
http://www.tempuri.org
http://www.tempuri.org//
http://www.tempuri.org///
ftp://www.tempuri.org////
file:///c:/path-to//file.ext
file:////c:/path-to/file.ext
file://///c://path-to/file.ext
```

And this is what I'm trying to get from these:

```
http://www.tempuri.org/path/to/file.ext
c:/path-to/file.ext
c:/path-to/file.ext
http://www.tempuri.org
http://www.tempuri.org/
http://www.tempuri.org/
ftp://www.tempuri.org/
file:///c:/path-to/file.ext
file:///c:/path-to/file.ext
file:///c:/path-to/file.ext
```

The closest I got was this:

```
(?<!(file:)|(ftp|gopher|http|https|ldap|mailto|net\.pipe|net\.tcp|news|nntp|telnet|uuid)[:])/+
```

But **replacing matches by a single slash** turns `file:///` to `file://`. Aside from that last case, seems to be working perfectly.

Comment: Do you need it done in a single pass? For example, can you split your strings into an array with the URI scheme in one and the rest of the path in another?

Comment: It's not a **must**, but it would be more elegant to do it in a single pass if possible. Right now I'm dealing with the `file:///` case separately but I'm hoping to get rid of that.

Comment: http://regex101.com/r/hU4yI4

Comment: By the way, +1 for providing your example code and expected result in your question!

Comment: This is an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/171858). What are you ACTUALLY trying to do, as you have given us a solution that does not work to a problem you have not described.

Comment: Actually, I did describe the problem. You can read it in the first paragraph: I need to remove duplicate slashes from a path except for the ones in the URI scheme. If you think there's a cleaner way than using RegEx please share your preferred method.

Comment: @AxelMagagnini Yes, but why do you need to do that? Is it because you're building paths up by concatenating strings? If so, look at `System.IO.Path.Combine()`.

Comment: @DanielMann I need to make sure that paths are normalized and specifically that there are no multiple combinations of the same "valid" (as in understandable by Windows) path pointing to the same file. That's why I need to remove multiple slashes, among other stuff outside the scope of this question. I have limited control on how these paths are created, so `Path.Combine()` is not enough in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm more familiar with PCRE format, but take a look at this:

```
(                     # Capture group

(?<!\/)\/             # Look for / that does not follow another /

# Look for C:/
(?(?<=\b[a-zA-Z]:\/)  # if...
                      # then look for any more / to remove
  |                   # else

# Look for file:///
(?(?<=\bfile:\/)      # if...
  \/\/                # then look for // right after it
  |                   # else

# Look for http:// or ftp://, etc.
(?(?<=:\/)            # if [stuff]:/
  \/                  # then look for /
  |                   # else

)
)
)
)
\/+                   # everything else with / after it
```

Live: http://regex101.com/r/hU4yI4

Essentially, I'm looking for these criteria using a [conditional statement](http://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html):

```
If / is preceded by:
   \b[a-zA-Z]:     then     /
   \bfile:         then     ///
   \b\w{2,}:       then     /   (basically anything else, like ftp:, https:, etc.)
```

Without all the whitespace, the entire group would look more like:

```
((?<!\/)\/(?(?<=\b[a-zA-Z]:\/)|(?(?<=\bfile:\/)\/\/|(?(?<=:\/)\/|))))\/+
```

I'm not sure how this would plug into C#'s regex, however. It may drop right in, or it may need some massaging (which is why I left the comments in the code for easier reading and more edge cases).

Comment: WOW, that was an amazing answer, specially because of the step-by-step comments, thanks! However, it seems that it does not work the same way in C#'s regex when dealing with excess slashes in `file:///`. You can see it working on http://regexhero.net/tester/?id=0494980d-bd07-4d3c-a8c0-258eba6d0c60.

Comment: Also +1 for breaking up the expression into more understandable components and pointing the if-then-else reasoning. I was thinking of lookbehinds the wrong way. I'm trying to figure how to make it work in C#, will report back.

Comment: Ok, got it working. Turns out I was using `regex.Replace(inputString, "/")` instead of `regex.Replace(inputString, "$1")` which uses the backreference. Thank you very much for your help!